# White square on top of the form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to display a white square in the upper part of a form but I have not the slightest idea how.

Like This:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

1. Drag a Panel control onto your form from the Containers section in your designer toolbox
2. Set the Dock property to Top
3. Resize it so it's as high as you want it
4. Set the backgorund color property to White

This is just one of a number of different ways that this can be accomplished. What do you plan on doing with this white area of the form?